# How to get matching pattern along with ID in a single command in grep?

Tags: fasta, motifs, grep

I have a file containing multiple fast sequneces. For a specific consensus pattern as input, I extracted all the matching patterns from target fasta sequences with

```
grep -o -E "CC[GT]AAA[GC][AC]TT[GC]" input.fasta
```

However, the above command will retrieve just the matching sequences from fasta sequences and **I  also wanted to get the corresponding fasta header of each match**.

For example, if **input.fasta**  file is something like this,

```
>Gene 1
TGATGAAAAATGATAGAT
ATTGGGGGAAAAAAAAAT

>Gene 2
TTTCCTAAAGATTGT
AAATTTAAAAATGTTTTT
```

(Gene 2 has matching subsequence CCTAAAGATTG)

Output:

```
CCTAAAGATTG   Gene2
```

I prefer a solution with grep. But other possible solutions also helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '$id = $1 if /^>(.+)/; ($m) = /(CC[GT]AAA[GC][AC]TT[GC])/; print join "\t", $id, $m if $m;' input.fasta
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)